# Eye Tracking for Eye Controlled Wheel Chair OpenCV+Python

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.1, eye-tracking

I am trying to implement a code the get the centroid of the eye and track the eye movement to control a wheel chair. The code applied on an image is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('eye pupil.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cl1 = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
clahe = cl1.apply(gray)

bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(clahe, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 12)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)

img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

draw = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, 5, (0,0,255), 2)

cv2.imshow('draw', draw)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and the output is:

[image: eye pupil] [image: centroid]

Definitely the code I wrote gives me a pretty well centroid to start off with. But when I try implement this on a video the output is so missy.

In the code for a video I use `haarcascade_righteye_2splits.xml` or `haarcascade_leftteye_2splits.xml` to be more specific for the camera on what to detect.

Any help how can I do an eye pupil tracking code on a video, left, right, and blink.

> I am using OpenCV 3.1.0-dev and Python 2.7.x

Comment: Take a look at the [Hough Circle Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html), it might help you !

Comment: @francis Alright 

Comment: @francis not giving me convenient results.

Comment: In the example you posted, the error seems to be due to the reflection of the ligtht in the eyes. Indeed, there is a small white zone in the pupil. As openings are performed, this white zone grows and translates the centroid to the opposite direction.